# XCUITest - Can't find the webview XCUIElement for HTML checkbox

Tags: html, xcode, checkbox, webview, xcuitest

I have tried

```
app.webViews.checkBoxes["id"].tap()
```

but xcode seems to can't detect the html checkbox. Apple's [official document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtypequeryprovider/1500365-webviews) lacks detail on this topic. Here's the [test log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVh3m.png) and HTML element

```
<div id="accept-id-arial">accept</div>
<input id="accept" style="border :1px solid red;" aria-labelledby="accept-id-arial" name="accept" type="checkbox" value="0">
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

P.S. I have been trying to search for a reference of webview XCUIElement and html element, but couldn't find one. Please share if you happen to know one.

Comment: Your best bet is to look inside to see what's in it, so `print(app.webViews.debugDescription)`.

Comment: @Alper All webView shows from print() is `Find: Target Application 0x6000000bee40
  Output: {
    Application, 0x6040003815f0, pid: 38164, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}, label: 'dbg-ラジオクラウド'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type WebView
    Output: {
      WebView, 0x604000192210, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
    }` Thanks anyway.

Comment: I know this is an older thread, but when I print this out still now, I see the same thing as above.  With the move to inheriting web views from web sites and displaying them in mobile apps, this is something that should be improved upon, especially for writing XCUITests.